# Update Elasticsearch document which has multiple array

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I have a requirement to update document (bulk) in the elasticsearch 5.X

Conditions

1. I have to update a groupname based on the groupid.
2. A block will have multiple group id block.
3. I need to update group name for only groupid 245.If i update one block another block should not get affected. It should remain as it is.
4. I have to update them in bulk.

   ```
   {
   "hits": [{
       "_index": "myindex",
       "_id": "1",
       "_source": {
           "TicketSet": [{
               "Tasks": [{
                   "Group": {
                       "Id": 245,
                       "Name": "Name 245"
                   }
               }, {
                   "Group": {
                       "Id": 244,
                       "Name": "Name 244"
                   }
               }]
           }]
       }
   }, {
       "_index": "myindex",
       "_id": "3",
       "_source": {
           "TicketSet": [{
               "Tasks": [{
                   "Group": {
                       "Id": 245,
                       "Name": "Name 245"
                   }
               }, {
                   "Group": {
                       "Id": 244,
                       "Name": "Name 244"
                   }
               }]
           }]
       }
   }]
   ```

   }

Answer (score 0):

You can do so easily with the [update by query API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update-by-query.html) (I made the assumption that `ticketdesc` is `nested`):

```
POST tickets/_update_by_query
{
  "query": {
     "term": {
       "TicketSet.Tasks.Group.Id": 245
     }
  },
  "script": {
    "inline": "ctx._source.TicketSet[0].Tasks.stream().filter(g -> g.Group.Id == params.groupId).forEach(g -> g.Group.Name = params.newName)",
    "params": {
      "groupId": 245,
      "newName": "New name"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: No it's not nested... It's a normal array. Can we do anything about that.

Comment: i have updated the json structure. This is what i'm using it now. Can you help me out in this.

Comment: No it's not nested. I have tried the above query. It just keeps on running.. I'm not getting any response..

Comment: Got this error {
"error": {
"root_cause": [
{
"type": "parse_exception",
"reason": "expected one of [inline], [file] or [stored] fields, but found none"
}
],
"type": "parse_exception",
"reason": "expected one of [inline], [file] or [stored] fields, but found none"
},
"status": 400
}

Comment: You have an old version of ES, I've updated my answer, please try again

Comment: I am using ElasticSearch Version 5.4., I'm still getting the error. By the way there is no nested type in the document everything is an array.                           
{
"type": "script_exception",
"reason": "runtime error",
"script_stack": [
"ctx._source.TicketSet[0].Tasks.stream().filter("
,
" ^---- HERE"
],
"script": "ctx._source.TicketSet[0].Tasks.stream().filter(g -> g.Group.Id == params.groupId).forEach(g -> g.Group.Name = params.newName)",
"lang": "painless"
}